# Can an array be assigned with a initializer list?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm reading C++ Primer 5th, and a chapter about containers says something about  assignment, it's quoted here:

"...

```
c = {a,b,...};
```

Replace the elements in c with copies of the elements in the initializer list.(not valid for array)... "

Then I tried on VS2016:

```
array<int, 2>ai;
ai = { 1,3 };
for (auto c : ai) {
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

Surprisingly, this could work, no error occured.

So I just wanna know, is it right that an array can be assigned with a initializer list? Or it's just because of the compiler?

Comment: See list-initialization: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's defined to be assignable as such:

> Class `array` relies on the implicitly-declared special member functions
>   (12.1, 12.4, and 12.8) to conform to the container requirements table
>   in 23.2.

You can use the initializer list syntax because `array`'s constructor is not `explicit`. Otherwise you'd have to say something like the following:

```
ai = array<int,2>{ 1,3 };
```